# Syntax Highlighting not working with Prismjs

Tags: ghost-blog, prismjs

I am running ghost as a blog software and I have a blog post that has markdown code snippets that I would like to have syntax highlighted.

I have followed the instructions to include the necessary header and footer tags and the specific tag for the language Im trying to highlight but still no syntax highlighting is taking place.

Here is a link to the page Im trying to get syntax highlight working on:

https://screaming-cactus.com/learning-to-love-result/

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please show the code how you tried to return it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the original poster is still in need of this, but if anyone is looking to syntax highlight their code blocks in Ghost and stumble upon this page, I've created a tutorial that shows you how: https://ghost.org/tutorials/code-snippets-in-ghost/

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: It redirected for me. I've updated the link anyway